# Get Node at Line in Python?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have an XML that works like a finite-state machine and and I want to store the progress throughout different sessions in a database, so I thought a simple way of doing this would be to simply store the line of the node the FSM is currently at. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<states>
    <state id = "1">...what can you do in state 1?</state>
    <state id = "2">...what can you do in state 2?</state>
<states>
```

And, assuming the machine is in **state 2**, I would simply store the database *4* (since it's the line the node describing **state 2** starts at.
Is there in python (maybe *minidom*) a nice way of

1. getting the line a given node starts at (when saving)
2. getting the node at a given line (when restoring)

Comment: Why store line numbers when you can just store the state?  If you're in state 2, store _2_, then reload to that state.  Attempting to depend on line numbers will ruin your implementation if the content between `<state>` and `</state>` ever encompasses more than a single line.

Comment: I oversimplified the example, but unfortunately it's not as simple as relying on the state number, instead that exact node in the XML file would make my life easier. In the example I presented, though, I agree that your implementation would make much more sense.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the line numbers will always match up.  The internal representation of the document in memory (after it's loaded by the DOM Parser) isn't going to note or remember what line a node started on (presuming the parser even operates on a line-by-line basis, which isn't guaranteed).  More importantly, the differences in parsers / writers may affect how the doc is saved out each time.  You're never going to get the type of consistency you would if you simply stored the state.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to do this, is because the XML I'm working with is an XML returned by a third-party library which is an FSM whose states are not labeled as "S1", "S2"...and so on. Instead, I'd have to look into the subnodes and parse them in order to see exactly which state I'm into, and then store the subnode values too. That's why I thought that simple storing a file line would have made my life easier :)

Comment: I'd store an `xpath` to the node if you can't just store the state number.